# Can't start tomcat after installing it on Ubuntu 16.04: "Job for tomcat.service failed because the control process exited with error code."

Tags: 16.04, tomcat

I followed the steps https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04 to install [tomcat 8.5.24](http://apache.cs.utah.edu/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.24/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.24.tar.gz) on Ubuntu 16.04, till running `sudo ufw allow 8080` in "Step 6: Adjust the Firewall and Test the Tomcat Server".

Then I can't start tomcat,

```
$ sudo systemctl start tomcat
Job for tomcat.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status tomcat.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

and the link `http://localhost:8080/` doesn't work in both firefox and google chrome browsers.

I was wondering how to solve the problem.

The following details are what I followed the above output messages of `sudo systemctl start tomcat`. It seems that `/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh` succeeded while `/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh` failed. Much appreciate your help!

```
$ systemctl status tomcat.service
● tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-12-01 18:55:30 EST; 2s ago
  Process: 19490 ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 19478 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 19440 (code=exited, status=127)

Dec 01 18:55:30 ocean systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 01 18:55:30 ocean systemd[1]: Failed to start Apache Tomcat Web Application Container.
Dec 01 18:55:30 ocean systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 01 18:55:30 ocean systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

$ journalctl -xe

-- Unit tomcat.service has begun starting up.
Dec 01 18:51:24 ocean startup.sh[18873]: Existing PID file found during start.
Dec 01 18:51:24 ocean startup.sh[18873]: Removing/clearing stale PID file.
Dec 01 18:51:24 ocean startup.sh[18873]: Tomcat started.
Dec 01 18:51:24 ocean shutdown.sh[18885]: PID file found but no matching process was found. Stop aborted.
Dec 01 18:51:24 ocean systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 01 18:51:24 ocean systemd[1]: Failed to start Apache Tomcat Web Application Container.
-- Subject: Unit tomcat.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit tomcat.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Dec 01 18:51:24 ocean systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 01 18:51:24 ocean systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 01 18:51:34 ocean systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 01 18:51:34 ocean systemd[1]: Stopped Apache Tomcat Web Application Container.
-- Subject: Unit tomcat.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit tomcat.service has finished shutting down.
Dec 01 18:51:34 ocean systemd[1]: Starting Apache Tomcat Web Application Container...
-- Subject: Unit tomcat.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit tomcat.service has begun starting up.
Dec 01 18:51:35 ocean startup.sh[18896]: Existing PID file found during start.
Dec 01 18:51:35 ocean startup.sh[18896]: Removing/clearing stale PID file.
Dec 01 18:51:35 ocean startup.sh[18896]: Tomcat started.
Dec 01 18:51:35 ocean shutdown.sh[18908]: PID file found but no matching process was found. Stop aborted.
Dec 01 18:51:35 ocean systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 01 18:51:35 ocean systemd[1]: Failed to start Apache Tomcat Web Application Container.
-- Subject: Unit tomcat.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit tomcat.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Dec 01 18:51:35 ocean systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 01 18:51:35 ocean systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

My Java versions are

```
$ java --version
java 9.0.1
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)

$ javac --version
javac 9.0.1
```

---

**update:**

Instead of `sudo systemctl start tomcat` which gives the error above, if I run

```
cd /opt/tomcat/bin

sudo ./catalina.sh run
```

http://localhost:8080/ shows the correct webpage. SO what is the reason that one doesn't work while the other does?

Comment: Please reload the firewall with `sudo ufw reload`

Comment: Thanks, but `sudo ufw reload` doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Then restart it `sudo systemctl restart ufw`

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem either.

Comment: I updated my post with my java version. i am using Oracle java 9.0.1.

Comment: I doubt your tomcat supports java 9 see here: http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Comment: I updated at the end with some other way.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me too. What helped was to delete this file: /opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid

This is a temp file create by tomcat on startup. Apparently, if it exists for some reason, the service will fail to start. –

Answer (score 0):

For me has working run

```
sudo sh -c 'chmod +x /opt/tomcat/latest/bin/*.sh'
```

I took this tutorial

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-tomcat-8-5-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: Why would you invoke `sh` when you can just use `chmod` with `sudo`?

Comment: well, I just followed the tutorial he forced the use with `sudo`, but i think that if you execute a command with `sh -c` the dash shell will be used to execute the command instead of bash.

Comment: `chmod` isn't a shell built-in command. `/bin/chmod` will be called no matter which you use. Just fyi.